# USSD Code returns unknown characters

Tags: htc-one, ussd

My new HTC One phone is showing some problems while running USSD codes on it. I am using BSNL network. So I have to use the code *123# for knowing the balance. When I tried to run the same, I am getting something displayed in some other language:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Check Settings > Language & Keyboard...

Comment: Yea. I checked it. But it is set as English.

Comment: But is the code functional?

Comment: Could be carrier related, never seen this before, why are you getting japanese/kanji symbols even if the language/keyboard is set to English?

Comment: @shub Sorry. I didn't get your question. Every valid USSD returns something like this. But my mobile is displaying them in the way as it is in the screenshot.

Comment: @t0mm13b i found some others facing the same problem on visiting some forums. But unfortunately the question posted by them are unanswered.

Comment: What is your android version? Are you using custom rom?

Comment: Android version : 4.4.2
Not rooted!